# Extracting XML from XMLFormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, infopath

Is there a way to get the XML presented in a XMLFormView? I'm trying to create a custom web part with a "Save as PDF" button for an InfoPath form. The idea is to combine the XML with the form's XSL and make the resulting HTML into PDF which is presented to the user as a popup.

Because it is to be presented as a popup, using Workflows is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the `XmlFormHostItem.NotifyHost` method to send HTML to a custom web part in a button-clicked event, which converted the HTML to PDF using Winnovative HTML to PDF converter.

HTML generation from InfoPath code-behind:

```
var formData = new XmlDocument();
var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

// Load the form data 
formData.LoadXml(MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().InnerXml);
// Extract the stylesheet from the package
xslt.Load(ExtractFromPackage("Print.xsl")); // (uses Template.OpenFileFromPackage(string fileName) to get xsl)

// Perform XSL-transformation
// [...]

// Send HTML to web part
this.NotifyHost(formData.InnerXml);
```

One drawback of this method is that the NotifyHost event only fires once per form, so if the user clicks 'Save as PDF' and then cancels, he must reload the form in order to be able to save as PDF.

Comment: A much better way would have been to get the XML directly from the custom web part.Don't know why we didn't do that in the first place. Random tardiness, i suppose :)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.infopath.server.controls.xmlformview.xmllocation.aspx

This property will give you the Url of the Base XML file. You can read the Stream reader to read this XML.

Comment: As far as I can tell, XmlLocation is only set if you reference XML-data in the form. If you use XslLocation (as we do), XmlLocation is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my codeplex project http://ip2html.codeplex.com/

It allows you to generate HTML from the given (InfoPath) XML & (XMLFormView) XSLT.